# Managing multiple concurrent threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm writing a multi-threaded program in C++ using C++11 threading library.

I have the following requirements:

1. Main thread listens to some type of events, and fires off a new thread for each new event
2. When program termination is requested, new thread creation is blocked and we wait for the old threads to finish

I have the option to store the threads in some container, for example, a list. Before exit, all threads in the container are `join()`-ed. However, since STL containers are not thread-safe, additional synchronization is needed when adding a new thread and removing a finished thread from the container. The interaction between the main thread and the child threads becomes a little more complicated in this case. Should the child thread remove itself from the container? If not, how does it let the main thread know when it's time to remove? etc.

Another way I see is to have an atomic int which is incremented by the main thread when a child thread is created, and decremented by the child thread right before its termination (threads will be `detach()`-ed after creation, so I won't have to manage any std::thread objects). Before exiting, we just wait for the atomic integer to become 0 in a simple loop. This solution looks better to me because there are less moving parts and no locking (at least as long as the target platform has a lock-free implementation of `std::atomic<int>`).

So, my question is, which of the above methods would you prefer?

Comment: Do you need a new thread for every event? If you have a lot coming in, and especially if they are short, thread creation/destruction will be a huge overhead. Depending on your situation you may want to implement some sort of thread pool, with a fixed number of worker threads. Just a suggestion

Comment: If the main thread is already listening to events, why can't the child threads just send the main thread an event signaling that it's finished? Then only the main thread will ever touch the container and no synchronization is needed.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy I know, but it was a conscious choice. I do not have a lot coming in and the child threads can take considerable time to finish, so I don't see a need to use a thread pool yet.

Comment: @ildjarn The thing is, those events are not generated within the application's code, they are events generated a by third-party library. I don't have any control over those events (i.e. can't trigger them).

Comment: Do you absolutely need to wait for the threads to finish, is there some resource bound to them that absoluetly needs to be closed/stopped/finalized explicitly?

Comment: Yes, the threads need to produce some data which needs to be reported back and failure to report that data is not an option.

Comment: Also, note well Alexandr etc. comments - continually creating/terminating/destroying threads is not only avoidable overhead, it also involves you in thread micro-management that usually ends badly.

Comment: @Grigory - in that case, I would probably message the data back and keep a count of outstanding messages for events that have not been fully handled.  On a shutdown request, I woudl stop issuing any mor events to the threads and count down the outstanding replies until zero. I would do that just to avoid join() and any direct thread management.  I'm sure you will think this over-complex:)

Comment: No, simpler than managing threads in a container :-) Actually, this looks similar to the second of my proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the thread counter would be my choice, combined with a condition wait. The last thread exiting should signal the condition variable to wake up the waiter.

```
// the waiter
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(threads_lock);
    while (threads > 0) {
        threads_cond.wait(threads_lock);
    }
}
//...

// the threads that are exiting
if (--threads == 0) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(threads_lock);
    threads_cond.notify_one();
}
```

This is assuming that `threads` is `std::atomic`, of course.